# Set enter key behavior on aspx form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

Have the need to alter the behavior of pressing enter on my aspx page based on the last control that was interacted with.  I have two textboxes and a dropdown.  Each one of those controls has a corresponding button that takes the input and applies it to other fields on the page.  Much like adding options to a master part.

Example: If button2 is pressed, the option in textbox2 would be applied, but not the option in textbox1, or the dropdown. The page is refreshed, and the user can continue to select options.

How would I alter the page to allow the user to type in text in a textbox and then hit enter to activate the code for the corresponding button.  I've tried various js to set the page default, but have been unsuccesseful in  changing this on the fly.

Comment: use the javascript onBlur event on each element which will execute when the element loses focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ASP.Net Panel control's DefaultButton to accept enter key.

http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2006/04/12/74951.aspx

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server" defaultbutton="Button1">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="pnl2" runat="server" defaultbutton="Button2">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button2" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set event listeners for a user modifying the inputs and set a reference to the proper button. Then have a listener for the enter button to trigger submitting the referenced button. You didn't mention jQuery or any JS framework so I'll try writing it generally for plain javascript, I'd recommend using a framework though for cross browser support.

```
var myButtonId = null;

var storeInputButtonId = function(buttonId) {
  return function(event) {
    myButtonId = buttonId;
  };
};

//Do following for inputs, or your preferred event binding pattern
var fld = document.getElementById('myInputId');

//Statically refer to button id or replace with suitable algorithm
var inputButtonId = "";
if (fld.addEventListener) {

  //Could bind to other events with logic based on input element type
  fld.addEventListener('keyup',storeInputButtonId(inputButtonId), false);
}


//Method to trigger the button click event
function submitData(event){

  //Watch for the enter button
  if ( event.which == 13 ){
    document.getElementById(myButtonId).click();
  }
} 

//Bind the listener to the enter button
var bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

if (bodyElement.addEventListener) {

  bodyElement.addEventListener('keydown',submitData, false);
}
```